# Will the facebook old version work for new features?

Tags: ios, facebook

We are working on iOS App. We are providing a feature to sign in with **Facebook** and it is working fine.

The **Facebook** version integrated with my app already seems old (we are using code not really sdk as they are providing now) and we are trying to implement the posting related functionality.

My question is: Can we continue with the Same version? as new sdk is released now If I use the same version Is there any chance to miss any new feature.

Note: It is already working code, that why wanted to double check before integrate the new one.

Comment: This is probably too vague/broad for StackOverflow. It might be better to head back when you have a more specific programming-related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is kinda too broad/vague - but Facebook very strongly recommends you use the latest [iOS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios) rather than code against the API directly.

The SDK manages a proper, supported authentication flow, as well as things like the Native Share and Message dialogs.